# Problem With Thymeleaf Background Image Url

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I'm working on a Spring Boot project and I am using Thymeleaf. In one of my view page let's call it dashboard.html, I need to change background image.

I can change images source with Thymeleaf.

Example 1

```html
<img th:src="'/uploads/' + ${dashboard.dashboard_photo}" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
```

Works fine..

But, I cannot change background image with Thymeleaf...

```html
<div class="banner_w3lspvt" th:style="'background: url('/uploads/' + ${dashboard.dashboard_photo});'">
```

I tried everything I found. Yes I know the same question was asked before but none of these answers helped me at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. When you ask a question, please try to provide as much information as possible about the issue, like the stack trace, the log, or the unexpected behaviour.

Meanwhile, try the following:

```
th:style="'background: url(/uploads/' + ${dashboard.dashboard_photo} + ');'"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it works fine :). About "much information", I dont know which information i should give here ? :( thx for correcting me btw :)

Answer (score 0):

I think [Literal substitutions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions) work well for expressions like that.  For example:

```
<div class="banner_w3lspvt" th:style="|background: url(/uploads/${dashboard.dashboard_photo});|">
```